# javasound minim processing

Tags: java, processing, javasound, minim

I dont understand this problem and why its like this, can anyone help me out?

```
==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Don't know the ID3 code TXXX

==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Don't know the ID3 code TXXX

==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Don't know the ID3 code TXXX

==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Don't know the ID3 code TDEN

==== JavaSound Minim Error ====
==== Don't know the ID3 code TSSE
```

is it because im running processing 3.02?

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;

void setup(){
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player = minim.loadFile("deadmau5.mp3");
  player.play();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't errors. Those are simply warnings telling you that minim can't find the ID3 tags, so it can't figure out things like the artist or track name. These don't matter if all you want to do is play the track. You can ignore these warnings.

The reason you aren't hearing anything is because minim requires a `draw()` function. So add a `draw()` function to your sketch (it can even be empty), and you're all set.

I've tried your code (with an added empty `draw()` function), and it works fine in Processing 3.0.2. If you're still having trouble, make sure the track is in the `data` folder in your sketch directory.